# Is it possible to configure a .net runsettings file to include complex objects?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, typing

I'm looking at implementing a runsettings file for automated testing. Thing is, my variables are complex objects, and all I can find in the documentation about runsettings has simple key/value options, like so.

```
<TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
  <Parameter name="docsUrl" value="https://learn.microsoft.com" />
</TestRunParameters>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify a complex object like you might specify below (especially since TextContext.Properties returns an object, so I assume it's polymorphic in some sense?) and cast it to a given defined class

```
<TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="AdminUser" UserID="Admin" Password="P@55w0rd!" />
  <Parameter name="User" UserID="User" Password="P@55w0rd!" />
</TestRunParameters>
```

I realize I can do the below and manually create my object instances, but I'd really really like to avoid it if at all possible

```
<TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="AdminUserID" value="Admin"/>
  <Parameter name="AdminUserPW" value="P@55w0rd!" />
  <Parameter name="UserID" value="User"/>
  <Parameter name="UserPW" value="P@55w0rd!" />
</TestRunParameters>
```